# Python Schedule library not scheduling method properly

Tags: python, schedule

I am using following code to run schedule method. Method should run everytday at 1.53 EST.

```
def sayHello(self):
    print(f"hello {datetime.datetime.now()}")

def schedule_job(self):
    print(f"schedules jobs")
    schedule.every().day.at("02:18", "US/Eastern").do(self.sayHello)



    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        print("Scheduled jobs:", schedule.jobs)
        time.sleep(1)
```

I expect this schedule lib to call self.sayHello method only once a day. But it keeps calling in a loop

```
schedules jobs
hello 2023-07-06 00:18:09.949960
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
Scheduled jobs: [Every 1 day at 02:18:00 do sayHello() (last run: 2023-07-06 00:18:09, next run: 2023-07-06 23:18:00)]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The output and code don't seem to line up (the print statement's output doesn't show up) - you also didn't provide the relevant code for `sayHello`. Please provide something that allows people to actually reproduce your problem. Currently, we can only assume the problem is somewhere in the code you're not sharing.

Comment: @Grismar Edited the post to provide full code

Comment: Have you tried to run your "full code"? I'm pretty sure you haven't.

Comment: @Grismar Yes, i did. Thats how i am able to produce the output. I again copy pased latest code and op

Comment: Your code appears to be part of some class, that's not here. You've since changed both the code and the output, but the provided code still doesn't match the output - or at least it can't be run without writing more code. Have a look at [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please make a *working* example of your code.